# What's the difference between the "hg" and "mercurial" Homebrew formulae?

Tags: mercurial, homebrew

Homebrew has both an "hg" and a "mercurial" formula. Which one should I install if I want to use Mercurial from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew aliases `hg` to the `mercurial` formula.
They're exactly the same, and they install the same program(s).

You can demonstrate this with `brew info hg mercurial`.